# Typescript: Convert from hex number to string for CSS hex color

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, hex

I have the following code:

```
  const myNumber: number = 0xFFFFFF;
```

How can I convert `myNumber` to `'#FFFFFF'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `toString()` method and a `#`

```
const myNumber: number = 0xFFFFFF;
const hexString: string = '#' + myNumber.toString(16);  // '#ffffff'
```

Comment: I don't think this will work for certain hex values though